# Questions with no close votes appearing in the close vote queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I've just been offered the wonderful opportunity to review [this item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1221519).

> [image]

... but on closer inspection [it's got no close votes on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994767/access-a-variable-in-a-parent-function-from-an-iframe-javascript)?

> [image]

Is this [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design) (e.g I'm assuming this post *did* previous have a close vote, but has now aged away in ways I don't understand), or *should* questions with no *active* close votes be removed from the queue.

<sup><sup>p.s. If it's [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design), please expect my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) asking for this not to be the case ;).</sup></sup>

Comment: I wonder if this could also happen when an initial close vote is retracted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any time a user without the vote-to-close privilege flags the question for a canned vote-to-close reason, it is automatically added to the close votes review queue as a way of reviewing the flag. The reason they used for the flag is the one presented at the top. I can only imagine that it being removed from the queue by too many "Leave Open" votes would automatically dismiss the flag as well, but I cannot confirm that. The flag is dismissed if the question gets closed, though.

You'll also notice that in cases where someone flagged as an exact duplicate, their flag is included in the count when selecting *which* question is the duplicate.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks :).

Answer (score 5):

That question was flagged (I'm 10k on SO and can see it in https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?subtype=close ) with close as not a real question. So it has no votes, but it's in the close queue.

BTW I edited it but I don't expect that to change whether it's a real question or not.

Comment: Thanks. If you'd have been 10 seconds quicker you'd have got the accept as well ;).